# Escaping a MySQL query containing variables with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, wordpress

I'm running the following code on a WordPress website to query the database:

```
$entries = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `id`, `lead_id`, `form_id`, `field_number`, `value` FROM `wp_rg_lead_detail` WHERE `value` = \"John\" OR `value` = \"Smith\" OR `value` = \"22101\" ORDER BY `lead_id`" );
```

I'd like to replace the hard coded values with pre-defined variables. I've attempted to do so using the following code:

```
$entries = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `id`, `lead_id`, `form_id`, `field_number`, `value` FROM `wp_rg_lead_detail` WHERE `value` = " . $data['voterdata_FirstName'] . " OR `value` =  " . $data['voterdata_LastName'] . " OR `value` = " . $data['voterdata_VoterZip'] . " ORDER BY `lead_id`" );
```

Unfortunately, the second code block does not work. I've noticed that the `OR` and `ORDER BY` conditions are not being interpreted correctly, but I don't know how to fix the issue. My concatenation looks fine, so I'm assuming the issue is with escape sequences. Can anyone advise a solution?

Comment: This is a SQL injection waiting to happen.  Take a look at prepared statements and parameter binding, which will also have the side-effect of being easier to read and solving the quoting problem in your query.

Comment: Yes indeed. Check $wpdb->prepare() method and $wpdb documentation in general to avoid these kind of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for responding, guys. Here's the solution:

```
            $entries = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT `id`, `lead_id`, `form_id`, `field_number`, `value` FROM `wp_rg_lead_detail` WHERE ( `value` = %s OR `value` = %s  OR `value` = %s ) ORDER BY `lead_id`",
            array( $data['voterdata_FirstName'], $data['voterdata_LastName'], $data['voterdata_ZipCode'] )
            )
         );
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what is the question honestly. "Escaping the data for query", or "Making this to work properly" (from perspective issues with quotes), or both.

This way or another, you need to know that $wpdb->get_results() will use $wpdb->query() method (check definition of class [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L0))

Having this in mind, if you check wordpress documentation regarding this subject, you **NEED** to use $wpdb->prepare() for sure ( rule is: check [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) before implementation).

This will provide us something like:

```
$wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
       "SELECT `id`, `lead_id`, `form_id`, `field_number`, `value` FROM  `wp_rg_lead_detail` WHERE `value` = %s OR `value` = %s OR `value` = %s ORDER BY `lead_id`", 
        $name1, 
        $name2, 
        $name3 
    )
);
```

with assumption that names are properly defined above.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to quote your parameters, as they are effectively constants by the time mySQL sees them.

Try this:

```
$entries = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `id`, `lead_id`, `form_id`, `field_number`, `value` FROM `wp_rg_lead_detail` WHERE `value` = \"" . $data['voterdata_FirstName'] . "\" OR `value` =  \"" . $data['voterdata_LastName'] . "\" OR `value` = \"" . $data['voterdata_VoterZip'] . "\" ORDER BY `lead_id`" );
```

Better still, you can replace the ORs with a single IN clause:

```
$entries = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `id`, `lead_id`, `form_id`, `field_number`, `value` FROM `wp_rg_lead_detail` WHERE `value` = IN(\"" . $data['voterdata_FirstName'] . "\",  \"" . $data['voterdata_LastName'] . "\", \"" . $data['voterdata_VoterZip'] . "\") ORDER BY `lead_id`" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your queries aren't equivalent - you forgot to quote (and escape) your variables:

```
[...snip...] OR `value` =  " . $data['voterdata_LastName'] . " [...snip...]
                           ^---------------------------------^--- PHP string delimiters, not sql
```

So you're generating

```
OR `value` = foo
```

instead of

```
OR `value` = 'foo'
```